# In magento 2 on product collection both addFieldToFilter and addCategoryFilter is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, database, collection

I am trying to get the product based on the 3 rules.
1st rule -> the product should have been created within a month
2nd rule -> it should be belonging to a particular category
3rd rule ->it should not have any special price

My Code:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $previousMonthDate]);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

This is returning empty array any suggestions on applying filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check and try the below example code.
Check all your inputs in getting the collection date should be like as described for example.
Also, Category should be category object.

```
$objectManager    = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$pc = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

// Category
$cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryId = 3;
$category = $cat->create()->load($categoryId);


$collection = $pc->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => '2020-06-01 00:00:00']);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

$items = $collection->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());  
}
```

you can also refer below links for more information.
 -

- https://webkul.com/blog/product-collection-category-magento2/
- [Get product collection by category id on phtml file magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2)
- [Get all products of a category created between 2 days](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187102/get-all-products-of-a-category-created-between-2-days)
- https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-product-collection-by-category-id-in-magento-2/

For Special Price.
- https://meetanshi.com/blog/check-if-product-has-a-special-price-in-magento-2/

Thank you

Comment: Thank you it worked.